# Selenium EdgeDriver disable save password dialog

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, microsoft-edge

I have few Selenium Tests which is working perfectly fine on chrome and firefox. however when I run then on Edge 13 (on windows 10) it fails with following error. 
**Error**
Element is obscured

it's giving this error because the element I want to click is behind the "would you like to save you password for XXXX site"

Would someone let me know which capabilities should I set so this doesn't occur.

So far I have tried following things. However, it's not working.

```
capability.setCapability("disable-save-password-bubble", "true");
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution would be to turn off the save password feature:

```
Settings > View advanced settings > Offer to save password
```

Another solution would be to move the targeted element before clicking on it:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("...")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
element.click()
```

Comment: I was thinking to do the same. however, if I follow this approach probably I will have to do this for every element.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like currently there is **no pre-defined capability for disabling** the '*Save you password*' message. You can log a comment on [**Issue *#17647317***](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/17647317/) for EdgeDriver on Microsoft Page

Comment: Add capability to disable 'Save your password' message for Edge browser 

#5943 - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5943